# Arduino RC522 Bytes and hex

Tags: arduino

I'm quite new to the RFID scene and I need some help!
I need to get the values of my cards from my RC522 and they need to look like this.

Example 1:

```
byte card1[5] = {0xAD,0xB2,0xDB,0xEA,0x3E}; // card1
```

But at the moment I can only seem to get it to print the values out as decimals!
like this.

Example 2:

```
173 , 178 , 219 , 234 , 46
```

How do I get the serial numbers of the cards like in the first example?

UPDATE

```
 Serial.print("     ");
 if(data[0] < 16){
 Serial.print("0");
}
Serial.print(data[0],HEX);

if(data[1] < 16){
Serial.print("0");
}
Serial.print(data[1],HEX);

if(data[2] < 16){
Serial.print("0");
}
Serial.print(data[2],HEX);

if(data[3] < 16){
Serial.print("0");
}
Serial.print(data[3],HEX);

if(data[4] < 16){
Serial.print("0");
}
```

This is the code used for the arrays

```
  if (rfid.isCard()){ // Found valid card
if (rfid.readCardSerial()){ // Reads the card
  delay(1000);
  data[0] = rfid.serNum[0]; // Array's for Card serial number.
  data[1] = rfid.serNum[1];
  data[2] = rfid.serNum[2];
  data[3] = rfid.serNum[3];
  data[4] = rfid.serNum[4];
}
```

**

### EDIT 2

**

**original code for example 2**

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RFID.h>

RFID rfid(10,5); 

void setup()
{ 
Serial.begin(9600);
SPI.begin(); 
rfid.init();

}

void loop()
{
if (rfid.isCard()) {

      Serial.println("IS CARD");

      if (rfid.readCardSerial()) {

                    Serial.println(" ");
                    Serial.println("The serial number of the card is  : ");
        Serial.print(rfid.serNum[0],DEC);
                    Serial.print(" , ");
        Serial.print(rfid.serNum[1],DEC);
                    Serial.print(" , ");
        Serial.print(rfid.serNum[2],DEC);
                    Serial.print(" , ");
        Serial.print(rfid.serNum[3],DEC);
                    Serial.print(" , ");
        Serial.print(rfid.serNum[4],DEC);
                    Serial.println(" ");
                    delay(1555); // Delay before reading again


      }

}

rfid.halt();
}
```

Comment: Hexadecimal and decimal are just representations of same values. What output code are you using?

Comment: @LS_dev 
Im storing the data in 5 arrays for each byte. then I'm printing those bytes out See updated question!

Comment: Review your question: "Example 2" doesn't match your code at all. Some mistakes: There is only one array with 5 elements, not 5 arrays. Use `for`. C arrays are 0 based.

Comment: @LS_dev I was using that as an example. I have stopped using that now and instead im printing the arrays in the way I showed and this is the output
    ADB2DBEA2E

Comment: @LS_dev I have now posted the code I was using before for example two in the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
    Serial.print(i?", 0x":"{0x");
    if (rfid.serNum[i]<0x10) Serial.print("0");
    Serial.print(rfid.serNum[i], HEX);
}
Serial.println("}");
```